# PHP CURL post giving an unknown error

Tags: php, ajax, post, curl, request

- **I'm trying to get an AJAX response by posting parameters through PHP
  CURL POST request**
- I am in need to getting certain results from a website(data
  crawling).
- The website is using AJAX calls to get the populate results inside.
- I had inspected the AJAX request made in the site through firebug and when I 'POST'ed the same request URL through RESTClient debugger,I got the results as a JSON.
- Then I tried to POST this request URL through PHP CURL POST method, but I'm getting some invalid output.

**My Code**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://www.example.com/Hotel-Search?inpAjax=true&responsive=true';
$fields = array(
    'endDate'=>'04/15/2014',
    'hashParam'=>'b2c21a315f0a0fb3f0c39f60XXXXXX',
    'startDate'=>'04/14/2014',
);
$headers = array(
    'Accept:    application/json, text/javascript,text/html'
);

$agent = '  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
var_dump($result);

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
**string(20) "�"**
```

EDIT

With reference to the suggestion below, I have added

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
```

Now I'm getting error as follows,

```
Couldn't resolve host 'www.example.com'
```

Comment: Try add `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header to `$headers` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its `gzip` content to me. Use this header to handle this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
```

Comment: Thanks for this.But Now I am getting an error like 
**Couldn't resolve host 'www.example.com'**

Comment: No.I'm using it against my target website itself.

Comment: But you could able to get response for this url a while ago. And now you mean its raising this error after adding my suggestion? can you please remove my suggestion and run the code again? I believe you are messing somewhere else!

Comment: Commenting CURLOPT_ENCODING is giving the same old error, string(20) "�"

Answer (score 0):

add this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('x-requested-with' => 'XMLHttpRequest'), # don't return headers